# CURL: post form and get data from bash

Tags: php, linux, bash, curl

I am trying to submit a form from bash:

```
curl -X POST  --data-urlencode "login=123456" --data-urlencode "password=123"
 --data-urlencode "returnUrl=/Katalog/SekceCsv/846?katalog=501" http://xy.com/user/Login
```

Result:

```
Object moved to here.
```

I submit the form data to the `/user/Login` script and after a successful login the script redirects me to the value declared in "**returnUrl**". Maybe this is the point where curl fails to get response what I want (it is a csv file) from the "**returnUrl**".

What I found on Google: I need to enable follow redirect option with -L:

```
curl -X POST  -L --data-urlencode "login=123456" --data-urlencode "password=123"
 --data-urlencode "returnUrl=/Katalog/SekceCsv/846?katalog=501" http://xy.com/user/Login
```

Result:

```
Length Required. HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.
```

I can't find any more info how to resolve this problem.

I tried to create a simple html file with the form:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="LoginForm" action="http://xy.com/user/Login">

          <input type="hidden" value="/Katalog/SekceCsv/846?katalog=501" name="returnUrl" id="returnUrl">
          <input type="text" value="" style="width:150px;" name="login" id="login">
          <input type="password" style="width:150px;" name="heslo" id="heslo">

          <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

This is working, when I press submit, I get the csv file what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it working like that ?

```
curl -dL "login=123456&password=123&returnUrl=/Katalog/SekceCsv/846?katalog=501" http://xy.com/user/Login
```

Edit:

After reading your comments, I think you are trying something weird.

If you have a login page and another page to get, you should have 2 curl commands. You can use cookies to keep track of the successfull login.

Something like :

```
curl -X POST -L -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c -d "login=123456&password=123" http://xy.com/user/Login
curl -X POST -L -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c -d "returnUrl=/Katalog/SekceCsv/846?katalog=501" http://xy.com/user/
```

Just some assumptions...

Comment: I already tried that (pass variables in single line), but unfortunately not working. The form type must be POST, with GET login is unsuccessful.

Comment: With -d the POST is implicit

Comment: Hmmm, but without -X POST the login is unsuccessful.